# How to switch jpa dialect for specify tenant in multi-tenancy system

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I'm working on a multi-tenancy system. I have to complete a request that enable a tenant can have their own database. The databases may be difference between tenant.
This mean a tenant A can use MYSQL, tenant B can use SQL Server and so on. How enable to user to switch between database type depend on authenticated user ?
I'm using Spring data JPA and all tenant database information should be stored in database not in configuration files.

Could anyone give me some solutions or discuss about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't sound like multi-tenancy. Instead of hosting multiple tenants in a single database system, you seem to be hosting independent parties with their own databases.

Comment: I using schema-based multitenancy architecture. So I need to write extendable module.

Comment: You're using schema-based multitenancy, but you want additional databases for each tenant? What would those databases do, and why would they not be chosen by you?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set the dialect.

Hibernate detects the dialect automatically from the JDBC Driver.

Read more in the offical documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#portability-dialectresolver